# How to add a different background color for each section with a SVG image in front of it

Tags: html, css, svg, background

I'm trying to have a different background color for each individual section/div with a hexagon grid (SVG with transparent gaps) in front of it. Currently it looks like this and I'm woundering how to push the red background up so that it is about on the blue line? I tried with play with padding and margin but it didn't affect anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/668O5.jpg)

That's the current code:

```
body {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' viewBox='0 0 5044 2922'%3E%3Cpath fill='slategrey' d='M -780 110 L 780 110 L 1560 1461 L 780 2812 L -780 2812 L -780 110 M 1742 -1351 L 3302 -1351 L 4082 0 L 3302 1351 L 1742 1351 L 962 0 L 1742 -1351 M 1742 1571 L 3302 1571 L 4082 2922 L 3302 4273 L 1742 4273 L 962 2922 L 1742 1571 M 4264 110 L 5824 110 L 5824 2812 L 4264 2812 L 3484 1461 L 4264 110 Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") repeat;


/*
  display: grid;
  
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 1em;

  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;  */
}

.backgroundable {
 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "cell";

   /*resize: both;*/
  overflow: hidden;

}

.backgroundable::before {
  
  grid-area: cell;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1; /* move the background color layer _behind_ the body element */
}

/* you can use real elements, too, if you like */
.a::before {
  background: khaki;
  padding: -20px;
}

.b::before {
  background: red;
  margin-top: -40px;
  
}


.backgroundable-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  grid-area: cell;
  /*width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  padding: 1em;*/
}

}
```

And the that’s the html

```
<div class="backgroundable a">
 <div class="backgroundable-wrapper">content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>

<div class="backgroundable b">
  <div class="backgroundable-wrapper">more content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>

<div class="backgroundable c">
  <div class="backgroundable-wrapper">more content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could draw the **inside** of the hexagons, not its lines. You can then position 3 color **filled** ``<rect>`` behind the hexagons to color the "lines"

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do it, I'm not used to using svg, but here is my attempt:

- Call the svg on every div to add your color with `style='background-color:yourColor'`
- Apply `background-attachment: fixed` to your divs.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.a {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' viewBox='0 0 5044 2922' style='background-color:khaki'><path fill='slategrey' d='M -780 110 L 780 110 L 1560 1461 L 780 2812 L -780 2812 L -780 110 M 1742 -1351 L 3302 -1351 L 4082 0 L 3302 1351 L 1742 1351 L 962 0 L 1742 -1351 M 1742 1571 L 3302 1571 L 4082 2922 L 3302 4273 L 1742 4273 L 962 2922 L 1742 1571 M 4264 110 L 5824 110 L 5824 2812 L 4264 2812 L 3484 1461 L 4264 110 Z'/></svg>");
}
.b {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' viewBox='0 0 5044 2922' style='background-color:red'><path fill='slategrey' d='M -780 110 L 780 110 L 1560 1461 L 780 2812 L -780 2812 L -780 110 M 1742 -1351 L 3302 -1351 L 4082 0 L 3302 1351 L 1742 1351 L 962 0 L 1742 -1351 M 1742 1571 L 3302 1571 L 4082 2922 L 3302 4273 L 1742 4273 L 962 2922 L 1742 1571 M 4264 110 L 5824 110 L 5824 2812 L 4264 2812 L 3484 1461 L 4264 110 Z'/></svg>");
}
.c {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' viewBox='0 0 5044 2922'%3E%3Cpath fill='slategrey' d='M -780 110 L 780 110 L 1560 1461 L 780 2812 L -780 2812 L -780 110 M 1742 -1351 L 3302 -1351 L 4082 0 L 3302 1351 L 1742 1351 L 962 0 L 1742 -1351 M 1742 1571 L 3302 1571 L 4082 2922 L 3302 4273 L 1742 4273 L 962 2922 L 1742 1571 M 4264 110 L 5824 110 L 5824 2812 L 4264 2812 L 3484 1461 L 4264 110 Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.a, .b, .c {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>

<div class="b">more content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>

<div class="c">more content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
```

I leave here a second attempt by setting a mask for a container, but I only managed to change the grey color. Also, the text is behind the mask.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' viewBox='0 0 5044 2922'%3E%3Cpath d='M -780 110 L 780 110 L 1560 1461 L 780 2812 L -780 2812 L -780 110 M 1742 -1351 L 3302 -1351 L 4082 0 L 3302 1351 L 1742 1351 L 962 0 L 1742 -1351 M 1742 1571 L 3302 1571 L 4082 2922 L 3302 4273 L 1742 4273 L 962 2922 L 1742 1571 M 4264 110 L 5824 110 L 5824 2812 L 4264 2812 L 3484 1461 L 4264 110 Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' viewBox='0 0 5044 2922'%3E%3Cpath d='M -780 110 L 780 110 L 1560 1461 L 780 2812 L -780 2812 L -780 110 M 1742 -1351 L 3302 -1351 L 4082 0 L 3302 1351 L 1742 1351 L 962 0 L 1742 -1351 M 1742 1571 L 3302 1571 L 4082 2922 L 3302 4273 L 1742 4273 L 962 2922 L 1742 1571 M 4264 110 L 5824 110 L 5824 2812 L 4264 2812 L 3484 1461 L 4264 110 Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.a {    
  background-color: khaki;
}
.b {
  background-color: red;    
}
.c {
  background-color: slategrey;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class="b">more content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class="c">more content!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had the problem that the grid isn’t symmetrical when I put the svg in each section. For example the hexagon became to long or to short on the transition from 1 section to the other and each section has a different height

Comment: @Anto It seems that I don't have the problem you're describing on my snippet.
Also please note that I tryed to solve your problem but I'm not confident about my answer, see it as an hint that could be useful but could be improved.

Comment: I know, thanks. I’m just telling the issues I had when I tried the approach with putting a new copy in each div and that’s why I went with this approach instead now